# _MISSING LABEL__ PropertyFile - val CustomTabLimitsServiceImpl$WithDetails_desc

Tags: deployment, package-install

I am facing a Package Installation error as shown below. It is happening only in one sandbox and Package installed successfully in other sandboxes. I searched a lot but could not find the correct solution for this. What needs to be done for this?

> **MISSING LABEL** PropertyFile - val CustomTabLimitsServiceImpl$WithDetails_desc not found in section Exception

Comment: In case you haven't already, take a look at the result of Googling "\_\_MISSING LABEL\_\_" in case one of those 4 or so results helps you.

Answer (score 0):

First, any time you see a "missing label" error, you should log a case with technical support; it's a bug. Second, the error implies that you would go over your tab limits if the process completed. Either delete some tabs or uninstall unnecessary packages.